# Show which php scripts Apache is currently running

Tags: php, linux, apache

When I run `ps -ef` from the Linux command line I don't see the php scripts currently being run by Apache web users, I just see the process as:

```
/usr/bin/php5-cgi -q -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini
```

Is there a command line that will show which script is being run, rather than just the fact the Apache user is using php?

Answer (score 8):

You can get the current working directory and opened files using lsof.
Sadly this does not include the script being run, but if scripts are in
different directories, or open different files, you can distinguish between
them. Eg the following shows a script in /var/www/stuff/php is running:

```
sudo lsof -c http | grep cwd
httpd   24475  id  cwd DIR 8,3     4096 1123403 /var/www/stuff/php
```

---

You can configure apache to let you have the information. Add an entry like

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    ...
</Location>
```

in your conf ensuring it is only made available to restricted remotes.
Then browse to `http://localhost/server-status` and you will have a "ps" of
running jobs. For example, this output shows gg.php is running (I've
removed some columns):

```
Srv PID     Acc     M CPU     SS Slot Client  VHost  Request
0-0 23688   0/0/262 W 0.50    2  4.48 ::1     xxx:80 GET /php/gg.php HTTP/1.1
1-0 23743   0/0/187 W 0.00    0  3.30 ::1     xxx:80 GET /server-status HTTP/1.1
```